# Does PyQt has support for QTest macros like QTRY_VERIFY

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtestlib, qtest

Does PyQt has support for QTest macros like [QVERIFY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#QVERIFY) and more importantly [QTRY_VERIFY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#QTRY_VERIFY) etc

I've looked around but couldn't find it but maybe I'm overlooking something

If not, what is the best way to support this functionality?  I'd rather not use `qtbot` since we are using both Python and C++ and I prefer to use the same testing framework on both code bases.

Comment: No. You cannot use `QTest` without `unittest`. What do those macros do that python's [assert methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) can't do?

Comment: That's indeed true for eg QVERIFY but not for the QTRY* macros.  These "evaluate a condition repeatedly until it becomes true or the timeout (in milliseconds) is reached. Between each comparison, events will be processed" 
 
This is a convenient macro to check whether a widget becomes visible (or enabled) ... , especially useful when we can't spy on signals

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't write a wrapper function that does the same thing. I suggest you take a look at [*qtbase/src/testlib/qtestcase.h*](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/testlib/qtestcase.h) and port whatever bits you actually need.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  That's definitely feasible.  But I was wondering whether it was part of PyQt.  I guess it isn't?

Comment: This isn't really the right place to discuss things like this, since the author of pyqt will never see any of it. If you want to know whether these macros could ever become part of pyqt, you should ask on the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).